# How to set static IP address to UDHCP client?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, static-ip

I am using udhcp client for an embedded device. I am trying to add a feature to set a static IP, Netmask, DNS, and gateway address.

I am trying to set it through the "-r" argument (request):

```
/sbin/udhcpc -A 3 -f -s /tmp/udhcpc_wlan0_sh -i wlan0 -r 172.16.0.2
```

It does not seem to work. I try to connect my device to an access point and it still used the dhcp deamon provide address.

I was wondering if there are any additional things that I need to do to enable static address.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this question [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/setting-static-ip-address-to-udhcp-client-4175645265/) (which appears to be yours as well), my conclusion is that you can’t assign a static IP. However, if you have the MAC address, you can assign an IP address as reserved on the dhcp server for that device with its MAC address.